# TypeScript Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'. React Jest Testing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs

Currently without TypeScript this code is working, but now it is not working unfortunately. It gave me the following error: **Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.** Not sure what is wrong with this. Seems it is nagging about the value. In this case I am using Jest testing and React. Not sure if I can ignore this error or should fix this in order to avoid weird bugs in the future.

```js
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getData } from '../../../actions/index';;

export const SearchInput : React.FC = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    let input: any;

    const getInputValue = (value: string):void => {
        let url = `https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${value}`
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1>Keyword</h1>
            <form className="form display-inline-flex" 
                onSubmit={e => {
                e.preventDefault()
                if(!input.value.trim()) return;

                getInputValue(input.value);
            }}>

                <input className="form-input-field disable-outline display-inline"
                    ref={node => (input = node)}
                    placeholder="Search catalog"
                    aria-label="search-input" 
                />
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-grey white-color display-inline">
                    Search
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SearchInput;

// Jest testing
import React from "react"
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import { SearchInput } from "./SearchInput";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "../../../Store";

const setup = () => {
    const utils = render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <SearchInput/>
        </Provider>);
    const input = utils.getByLabelText("search-input");
    return {
        input,
        ...utils
    }
}

test("It should check if input field get the value passed", () => {
    const { input } = setup();
    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "search-bar-test" } })
    expect(input.value).toBe("search-bar-test")
});
```

[image: ct]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be good to go if you add a type assertion like:

```js
const input = utils.getByLabelText("search-input") as HTMLInputElement;
```